# Can I define a bean from an ApplicationContext whose class is saved in a jar file

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Can I define a bean from an `ApplicationContext` whose class is saved in a jar file?

I have many modules each stored into a Jar file and my application needs to load them in order to be executed. I'm using Spring Framework and I need to define for each module it's `ApplicationContext` which need the class path of the module's class. So, how can I extract the classes from the jar files and use them as beans in the application?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

consider below bean config

```
<bean id="simpleUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
```

**SimpleUrlHandlerMapping** is the class file present inside spring.jar

Comment: It raises an exception  :

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class

Comment: Which class? Are you using the example as is? Replace `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` with your own class, as long as your class in on the classpath.

Comment: decompile the jar and check whether class is available in the specified path

Answer (score 0):

You can try the component-scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.planner.pov" />
```

remember to add the context namespace..